# Algorithm for finding basis of a set of bitstrings?

Tags: algorithm, linear-algebra, bit-manipulation

This is for [a diff utility I'm writing](https://github.com/Quuxplusone/difdef) in C++.

I have a list of *n* character-sets {"a", "abc", "abcde", "bcd", "de"} (taken from an alphabet of *k*=5 different letters). I need a way to observe that the entire list can be constructed by disjunctions of the character-sets {"a", "bc", "d", "e"}. That is, "b" and "c" are linearly dependent, and every other pair of letters is independent.

In the bit-twiddling version, the character-sets above are represented as {10000, 11100, 11111, 01110, 00011}, and I need a way to observe that they can all be constructed by ORing together bitstrings from the smaller set {10000, 01100, 00010, 00001}.

In other words, I believe I'm looking for a "discrete basis" of a set of *n* different bit-vectors in {0,1}<sup>k</sup>. [This paper](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~pmiettin/papers/gradu.pdf) claims the general problem is NP-complete... but luckily I'm only looking for a solution to small cases (*k* < 32).

I can think of really stupid algorithms for generating the basis. For example: For each of the k<sup>2</sup> pairs of letters, try to demonstrate (by an O(*n*) search) that they're dependent. But I really feel like there's an efficient bit-twiddling algorithm that I just haven't stumbled upon yet. Does anyone know it?

**EDIT:** I ended up not really needing a solution to this problem after all. But I'd still like to know if there *is* a simple bit-twiddling solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking a disjoint set data structure, like [union find](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_find) turned on it's head (rather than combining nodes, we split them).

**Algorithm:**

Create an array `main` where you assign all the positions to the same group, then:

```
for each bitstring curr
  for each position i
    if (curr[i] == 1)
      // max of main can be stored for constant time access
      main[i] += max of main from previous iteration
```

Then all the distinct numbers in `main` are your different sets (possibly using the actual union-find algorithm).

**Example:**

So, `main = 22222`. (I won't use `1` as groups to reduce possible confusion, as `curr` uses bitstrings).

```
curr = 10000
main = 42222 // first bit (=2) += max (=2)

curr = 11100
main = 86622 // first 3 bits (=422) += max (=4)

curr = 11111
main = 16-14-14-10-10

curr = 01110
main = 16-30-30-26-10

curr = 00011
main = 16-30-30-56-40
```

Then split by distinct numbers:

```
{10000, 01100, 00010, 00001}
```

**Improvement:**

To reduce the speed at which `main` increases, we can replace

```
main[i] += max of main from previous iteration
```

with

```
main[i] += 1 + (max - min) of main from previous iteration
```

**EDIT:** Edit based on j_random_hacker's comment

Comment: I like it! Though I don't actually see the connection to union-find, where I'm accustomed to seeing each "vertex" assigned to its own distinct "component" initially (instead of all to the same group). Also I think confusion reduction is not the only reason to avoid `0`s in `main[]`: if all `main[]` values are `0`, then they will remain `0` till the end.  Finally it would be clearer to say `main[i] += max of main from previous iteration`.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the passes of the stupid algorithm at the cost of space.

Make a bit vector called `violations` that is `(k - 1) k / 2` bits long (so, 496 for `k = 32`.)  Take a single pass over character sets.  For each, and for each pair of letters, look for violations (i.e. `XOR` the bits for those letters, `OR` the result into the corresponding position in `violations`.)  When you're done, negate and read off what's left.

Answer (score 0):

You could give [**Principal Component Analysis**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) a try. There are some flavors of PCA designed for [**binary**](http://reference.kfupm.edu.sa/content/b/i/binary_principal_component_analysis_64940.pdfEMi7E96ycXD46LU1yXixQqjLmoZQ) or more generally for [**categorical**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_correspondence_analysis) data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not looking for heavyweight theory; I already know how to find the answer in ~20 lines of code and a nested for-loop. My question is just whether there's a cleverer, shorter, less-nested way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Since someone showed it as NP complete, for large vocabs I doubt you will do better than a brute force search (with various pruning possible) of the entire set of possibilities O((2<sup>k</sup>-1) * n). At least in a worst case scenario, probably some heuristics will help in many cases as outlined in the paper you linked. This is your "stupid" approach generalized to all possible basis strings instead of just basis of length 2.

However, for small vocabs, I think an approach like this would do a lot better:

1. Are your words disjoint? If so, you are done (simple case of independent words like "abc" and "def")
2. Perform bitwise and on each possible pair of words. This gives you an initial set of candidate basis strings.
3. Goto step 1, but instead of using the original words, use the current basis candidate strings

Afterwards you also need to include any individual letter which is not a subset of one of the final accepted candidates. Maybe some other minor bookeeping for things like unused letters (using something like a bitwise or on all possible words).

Considering your simple example:

First pass gives you a, abc, bc, bcd, de, d

Second pass gives you a, bc, d

Bookkeeping gives you a, bc, d, e

I don't have a proof that this is right but I think intuitively it is at least in the right direction. The advantage lies in using the words instead of the brute force's approach of using possible candidates. With a large enough set of words, this approach would become terrible, but for vocabularies up to say a few hundred or maybe even a few thousand I bet it would be pretty quick. The nice thing is that it will still work even for a huge value of k.

If you like the answer and bounty it I'd be happy to try to solve in 20 lines of code :) and come up with a more convincing proof. Seems very doable to me.

Comment: Resurrecting to comment that this algorithm can't be *quite* right, as it fails to distinguish `{"ab", "a", "f", "g"}` from `{"ab", "a", "fg"}`. In both cases, first pass gives you `a`; bookkeeping gives you `a,b,f,g`; but the correct answer for the second one is actually `a,b,fg`.

Comment: I think something like modify the bookkeeping to "include any substrings of the original words which are not a subset of one of the final accepted candidates" or something along those lines might work. Like I said, I didn't really want to put in the time for flesh it out and prove w/o a bounty :) In any case, Dukeling's is much better. Good question.